# Conditionally mutate dataframe based on multiple conditions R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have seen some similar questions, but none of them was exactly the same as the thing I want to do - which is why I am asking.

I have a dataframe (dummy_data) which contains indices of some observations (obs) regarding given subjects (ID). The dataframe consists only the meaningful data (in other words: the desired conditions are met). The last column in this example data contains the total number of observations (total_obs).

```
ID <-c(rep("item_001",5),rep("item_452",8),rep("item_0001",7),rep("item_31",9),rep("item_007",5))
obs <- c(1,2,3,5,6,3,4,5,7,8,9,12,16,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,2,4,6,7,8,10,13,14,15,3,4,6,7,11)
total_obs <- c(rep(6,5),rep(16,8),rep(9,7),rep(18,9),rep(11,5))

dummy_data <- data.frame(ID, obs, total_obs)
```

I would like to create a new column (interval) with 3 possible values: "start", "center", "end" based on following condition(s):

it should split total number of observations (total_obs) into 3 groups (based on indices - from 1st to the last - which is the value stored in the total_obs column) and assign the interval value according to the indices stored in obs column.

Here is the expected output:

```
ID <- c(rep("item_001",5),rep("item_452",8),rep("item_0001",7),rep("item_31",9),rep("item_007",5))
segment <- c(1,2,3,5,6,  3,4,5,7,8,9,12,16, 1,2,4,5,6,7,8, 2,4,6,7,8,10,13,14,15, 3,4,6,7,11)
total_segments <- c(rep(6,5),rep(16,8),rep(9,7),rep(18,9),rep(11,5))
interval <- c("start","start","center","end","end","start","start","start","center","center","center","end","end","start","start","center","center","center","end","end","start","start","start","center","center","center","end","end","end", "start","start","center","center","end")

wanted_data <- data.frame(ID, segment, total_segments, interval)
```

I would like to use use dplyr::ntile() with dplyr::mutate() and dplyr::case_when() but I could not make my code function properly. Any solutions?

Comment: What are the criteria to split the data into "start", "center", and "end" intervals? I don't find any criterion in your explanation.

Comment: @AbdurRohman, sorry, non-native here. In total_obs, the total length of observation period is given. The division is made based on this value - it shall be divided into 3 categories of possibly equal length ("start", "center", "end", just as dplyr::ntile() does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `dplyr::mutate()` and `dplyr::case_when()`.
The following should give you something to work off of.

```
dummy_data %>%
    mutate(interval = case_when(obs < (total_obs/3) ~ "start",
                                obs < 2*(total_obs/3) ~ "center",
                                TRUE ~ "end"))
# TRUE ~ "end" is the 'else' case when everything else is false
```

Which gives slightly different results.
I think more careful deliberation should be made regarding where the endpoints are for each interval, but if you know what you are doing, using a combination of `<=`, `%/%`, and `ceil()` should give you the result you desire.

Answer (score 1):

First, because `dummy_data$obs` is identical with`wanted_data$segment`, and `dummy_data$total_obs` is identical with `wanted_data$total_segments`, you just need to rename these columns.

For the interval column, here is one approach of creating it:

- group the data based on `segment` column
- create a column, say `tile`, and fill it with `ntile(segment)` results.
- create `interval` column, and use `case_when` to fill it with the category labels created from `tile`. It means, fill `interval` with "start" when `tile` = 1, "center" when 2, and "end" when 3.
- drop the `tile` column.

```
wanted_data <- dummy_data %>% 
  rename(segment = obs, total_segments = total_obs) %>%
  group_by(total_segments) %>% 
  mutate(tile = ntile(segment, 3)) %>% 
  mutate(interval = case_when(tile == 1~"start", 
                              tile == 2~"center", 
                              tile == 3~"end")) %>% 
  select(-tile)

wanted_data 

# A tibble: 34 × 4
# Groups:   total_segments [5]
   ID       segment total_segments interval
   <chr>      <dbl>          <dbl> <chr>   
 1 item_001       1              6 start   
 2 item_001       2              6 start   
 3 item_001       3              6 center  
 4 item_001       5              6 center  
 5 item_001       6              6 end     
 6 item_452       3             16 start   
 7 item_452       4             16 start   
 8 item_452       5             16 start   
 9 item_452       7             16 center  
10 item_452       8             16 center  
# … with 24 more rows
```

It's slightly different from `wanted_data$interval` that you showed because based on your comment, you said that the division into categories is just as `dplyr::ntile()` does.

Comment: The category assignment is based on what dplyr::ntile would do in case if it would be applied to the total_segment column - I can show it using pseudocode, because this is the point, where I cannot move further as I am obtaining errors/unwanted results. For instance, if the value in total_segments would be 14, I would like to apply something like this: dplyr::ntile(1:14,3), so the categories would be:1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 and if the table would contain only 5th, 7th and 14 segment, they would be assigned to 1st, 2nd and 3rd categories. Grouping by total_segments makes no sense in my case